# prevProps.xx and this.props.xx always same, even when xx changes

Tags: reactjs

I have very strange error in reactjs 16.10

simple react app with  two components 
A and B.
A component includes B component and passes one of its state values to it.

```
    <ModalBody> 
     <B {...this.props} xx={this.state.xx}  />
 </ModalBody>
```

and in Component B I am trying to compare properties inside

> componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)

but problem is they are alway same.. initialy they are undefined and once prop is set from parent they are both identical so

```
if( prevProps.xx!=this.props.xx)
```

always fails..

P.S I do not mutate state directly so thats not an issue.. property gets set correctly from parent..

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague example answer, but my guess is because **componentDidUpdate** is called even if the internal component B state updates and if the props didn't change but the state did, **prevProps** will of course be the same as **this.props** because **componentDidUpdate** wasn't triggered by a prop change.

**Check your state updates.**